Windows Server DNS failure
I am using Windows Server 2019. Suddenly, no browser could access any website. I've tried Chrome, Edge, and Firefox. Additionally, ping and nslookup also fail and time out, indicating that the destination is unreachable and DNS is not working.
Here are the steps I have tried so far:

Changed DNS Settings:

Switched to multiple DNS servers (e.g., 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1).
No change in behavior.


Restarted the Server:

Multiple restarts, but no improvement.


Checked Services:

Verified that DNS Client and other related services are running.


DISM and Service Operations:

Ran DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
Failed multiple times with error 0x800f081f or 0x800f0950
Ran  DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:X:\Sources\install.wim \limitaccess
Also Failed at 47%
Ran DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore.
Executed:
net stop wuauserv
net start wuauserv
net stop cryptsvc
net start cryptsvc
Ran:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

This time it completed successfully, and I restarted, yet still
DNS not working
Despite these attempts, I am still unable to access any website from the server. This issue impacts not only browsers but also command-line tools like ping and nslookup.





Any suggestions before resorting to a complete format would be greatly appreciated, as formatting will take a long time to restore everything.

If you have the ability, try cold restart - shut down, pull power for 20 seconds to let the 5Vsb line drain down, then plug in and restart. Net cards never lose power unless the chassis does, this sort of failure is the sort of thing I see a lot when a net card has been powered for a long time and has fragmented its internal memory.

@tsc_chazz Thank you so much man! you saved me. Please post your comment as an answer, and i will edit my question and expand in details in everything i've been through. maybe this will help someone in the future.

Shut down the server, unplug it from the wall, let it sit until all of the LED status lights go out (about 20 seconds), plug it back in, turn it on.
Network cards are always powered, even when the machine is nominally turned off, specifically to support Wake On LAN - bring a machine up from hibernation if network activity is directed at it. Even a powered-down machine will show network carrier and traffic lights. The problem is that many network cards get into an internal state where certain types of packets cannot be transferred; sometimes, for instance, a machine becomes unavailable to RDP even though it's still exposing its network file shares. And sometimes it just stops handling network traffic at all. I've never gotten a complete explanation for this, my best guess is that the internal memory of the card has gotten  fragmented with use to the point that overlong packets can no longer be reassembled. When this happens, my experience is that it cannot be cleared so long as the net card retains power; restart, hard reset, none of that does any good. And network diagnostics typically fail to find anything wrong... except that certain types of network traffic simply disappear. Hence the wall reboot. Getting the card to a completely cold state, without the 5V standby power, seems to be the only thing that will reliably clear the problem.
As a side note, I've seen this happen on every variant of Windows from XP on up to 10 and every variant of Windows Server from 2000 to 2023. It seems less frequent on server-grade hardware, and I've never yet seen it on Linux systems, though that last may simply be that I haven't got anywhere near as many Linux systems in service yet.
